# disconnect between time and timezone of Sys.time() in R

Tags: r

When I call the Sys.time() function, it displays the time for "GMT" but says its "IST". How is this possible? How can I change this?

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2016-03-02 08:38:48 IST"
```

IST is actually GMT +05:30 so it should display "2016-03-02 14:08:48 IST"

Whats going on here?

EDIT: As per requests in comments.

I am using this computer in India on "IST" Indian Standard Time, which is my local time.

Here is the output for sessionInfo() as per request:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_IN.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_IN.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_IN.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_IN.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_IN.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] highfrequency_0.4   plyr_1.8.3          quantmod_0.4-5      quadprog_1.5-5      timeSeries_3022.101 timeDate_3012.100   TSA_1.01           
 [8] mgcv_1.8-7          nlme_3.1-121        locfit_1.5-9.1      leaps_2.9           tseries_0.10-34     TTR_0.23-0          xts_0.9-7          
[15] zoo_1.7-12          biglm_0.9-1         DBI_0.3.1           biganalytics_1.1.1  bigmemory_4.4.6     BH_1.58.0-1         bigmemory.sri_0.1.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.0     lattice_0.20-33 grid_3.2.2      Matrix_1.2-2    tools_3.2.2
```

Comment: ??? It's highly unclear at which (local) time you run the command.

Comment: Check the date and time of your system. In the documentation for Sys.time(), it is mentioned that it returns date and time of your computer.

Comment: (And to be complete, which system/OS and which version of R ?) (output of `sessionInfo()` would be great)

Comment: I have made the edits requested. Please help!

Comment: @KumarManglam. I understand that but the problem is that there is a disconnect with the time and time zone displayed. The time displayed is "GMT" while timezone displayed is "IST". Also, my computer is definitely on India Standard Time so why is it showing me "GMT" in the first place.